# Why does this simulate continuous assignment with delay of 2 as if had delay of 3

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have this system verilog code, that does continuous assignment for some simple operations with delays and a simple testbench with clocks.

```
`timescale 1ns/1ps

module delays(input logic a, b);
   logic bb, n1, n2;
   assign #1ns bb = ~b;
   assign #2ns n1 = bb;
   assign #2ns n2 = a & bb;
endmodule

module tb_delays ();
    reg a, b;

    delays mod(.a(a), .b(b));

    initial begin
        a <= 0;
        b <= 0;
    end

    always #4ns b <= ~b;
    always #2ns a <= ~a;
endmodule
```

I am running this and getting this result:

[image: scheme1]

I am getting the expected delay of `1ns` for `bb` and then expected delay of `2ns` for `n1`, but for some reason `n2` changes it's `x` state to `1` only after `3ns` after the value of `bb` have become known, instead of `2ns`.

What's interesting is if I get rid of `bb` and have `2ns` delay, then everything works as expected

```
module delays(input logic a, b); 
   logic n1, n2; 
   assign #2ns n1 = ~b; 
   assign #2ns n2 = a & (~b); 
endmodule
```

[image: scheme2]

And if I try to keep the same duration for the whole module, then `n2` never gets out of the `x` state.

```
module delays(input logic a, b); 
   logic n1, n2; 
   assign #3ns n1 = ~b; 
   assign #3ns n2 = a & (~b); 
endmodule
```

[image: scheme3]

All of this behavior seems rather weird to me and I cannot understand if this is actually to be expected or is it a tool bug. But either way I suspect it have something to do with the duration of the clock and that it is close to the duration of the simulation of the module, because if I set the clocks to be slower, then everything starts to work properly.

```
`timescale 1ns/1ps

module delays(input logic a, b);
   logic bb, n1, n2;
   assign #1ns bb = ~b;
   assign #2ns n1 = bb;
   assign #2ns n2 = a & bb;
endmodule

module tb_delays ();
    reg a, b;

    delays mod(.a(a), .b(b));

    initial begin
        a <= 0;
        b <= 0;
    end

    always #8ns b <= ~b;
    always #4ns a <= ~a;
endmodule
```

[image: scheme4]

My guess is it has something to do with event scheduling, but I am quite unsure of that as I am not experienced in this area and because I don't want to have gaps in my understanding any help is really welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as the *inertial delay model*—the LHS cannot change faster than the delay on RHS.

Basically, a continuous assignment can only have one pending scheduled update to the LHS at a time. In certain cases, a new scheduled update cancels the pending update.

This is defined in section *10.3.3 Continuous assignment delays* in the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595)

There other kinds of delay models to choose from using a variety of different constructs.